# How do I change the WPF Expander Header Text when expanded or collapsed?

Tags: .net, wpf, expander

Using a WPF expander, I want the Header to change from *See More* to *See Less* when the control is expanded, and back to *See More* when it's collapsed again.
I'd prefer a WPF pure solution, rather than a C# or other code behind method.
I get the feeling this should be easy, but I'm struggling for the right terms to get a solution via google.

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could probably do this in a style trigger:

```
<Expander>
    <Expander.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Expander">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="See More" />

            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsExpanded,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="See Less" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Expander.Style>
</Expander>
```

That's untested, but it should give you something to go on.

Comment: Consider it tested, and working exactly as I wanted. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Make sure you set the Header in the Style, and not in the Expander itself, otherwise the value in the Expander will take precedence over the Style Trigger.

Comment: You can use `Trigger` instead of `DataTrigger` if you want to use the control's `IsExpanded` property, like this: `<Trigger Property="IsExpanded" ...>`

Answer (score 9):

Old (I know), but this can be done with using two simple `Trigger` without binding:

```
<Expander>
    <Expander.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Expander" >
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="See Less" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="See More" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Expander.Style>
</Expander>
```